# Derivative of the function $f(x) = |x+2|$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I get the equation of the derivative $f(x) = |x+2|$ ?

I have already graphed the original function $|x+2|$ and the derivative function, but I'm not sure how to find the derivative, the equation and if it is differentiable at any points. Question says that the answer can be piece wise. Steps and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the derivative of the function $|x+2|$, or is that what you're trying to take the derivative of?

Comment: Just edited the question after checking. I need to find the derivative of f(x) = |x+2|. So far I just have the graph of it though.

Comment: $f'(x) = 1$ for $x > -2$ and $-1$ for $x < -2$ is no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\lvert x+2\rvert=\sqrt{(x+2)^2}
$$
The derivative of $f(x)=\lvert x+2\rvert$ can then easily be computed using the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
f^\prime(x)
&= \frac{d}{dx}\left\{\sqrt{(x+2)^2}\right\} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left\{(x+2)^2\right\}^{-1/2}\cdot 2\,(x+2) \\
&= \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{(x+2)^2}} \\
&= \frac{x+2}{\lvert x+2\rvert} \\
&=
\begin{cases}
-1 & x<-2 \\
\text{DNE} & x=-2 \\
1 & x>-2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Okay, this looks correct. Thanks! What would the equation be?

Comment: It would be the bottom line of the answer. That's what a piecewise definition of a function looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $|u|$ is $u$ if $u>0$ and $-u$ if $u<0$.  So when $x>-2$ we have $f'(x)=(x+2)'=1$ and when $x<-2$ we have $f'(x)=(-x-2)'=-1$.  $f'(-2)$ is undefined, which is easily seen using the limit definition.

Comment: Okay, so that would be the derivative of |x+2|, correct? Then how to find the quation?

Comment: undefined for -2 you mean I guess.

Answer (score -1):

if you need a formula for the derivative of $|x+2|$ it is $$\dfrac{x+2}{|x+2|}, x \neq -2.$$

the reason for this is $x + 2$ is $x + 2$ for $x > -2$ so the derivative is $1.$
similarly, $|x+2| = -x - 2$ for $x < -2.$ therefore the derivative is $-1$ for $x < -2.$ that is the piecewise definition.